# Invalid operands to binary (Comparing Double and Int in If statements) C Language

Tags: c, if-statement, operands

I am trying to make a Time Checker for my "Make a Grocery Store Project". Problem is that when I try to do an error-check for wrong userinput, it doesn't let me compare the two variables. I'm relatively new to coding so if you also have any problem with the way I layout my code and how I could improve, please do so.

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

 int tallytotal;
    int countertimeslots;
      double timeslots = 22.00;
int main() {
  
   
    void TimeSlotsPrinter(double t);
    printf("Please pick the total of items: ");
    scanf("%d", &tallytotal);
    countertimeslots = tallytotal;
        TimeSlotsPrinter(countertimeslots);
}
    
    
    
    
    
    void TimeSlotsPrinter(double t){
        if(countertimeslots >= 260){
            int v = 0;
            for(v; countertimeslots / 260 > v; ++v);
            printf("\nYou have chosen over %d items", countertimeslots);
            printf("\nThis means that you would have to wait %d additional day after tomorrow to pick up your items\n", v);
            countertimeslots -= 260 * v;
        }
            
            countertimeslots /= 20;
         double x = 9;
         x +=countertimeslots;
          printf("The time available is as follows..");
        for(x; timeslots>=x; ++x){
            printf("\n%.2lf", x);
         t--;
        }
        printf("\n**Beware that higher items means longer preparation time**");
        PickTime:
        printf("\nPlease enter your desired timeslot:");
        scanf("%d", &countertimeslots);
        
        if(countertimeslots << t && countertimeslots >> 22){
            printf("\nUnavailable time. Please pick another");
            goto PickTime;
        }
        
        else if(countertimeslots % 12 << 1){
            printf("You have selected %dAM", countertimeslots);
        }
        else
        {
            countertimeslots -= 12.00;
            printf("You have selected %dPM", countertimeslots);
        }}
```

*Error

I expected this to work since when you divide integer 1 in C with any integer greater than that, it would always produce 0.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7xpl.png)

Comment: [Please do not post images of text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: `<<` and `>>` are *bitwise-shift* operators. You may want to use `<` and `>` for comparisions. Boting to close as typo.

Comment: You call the `TimeSlotsPrinter` function passing `countertimeslots` as an argument. Then you use both `countertimeslots` and `t` in different situations. Note that once in the `TimeSlotsPrinter` function there's no relation between `countertimeslots` and `t`. Any modifications you make to either variable will not be reflected in the other. And generally, don't use global variables, pass arguments.

Comment: And don't use `goto` as a replacement for a loop. Use an actual loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(countertimeslots << t && countertimeslots >> 22){
```

`<<` and `>>` are bitwise-shift operators. They do not mean *very greater* and *very less.*

You may compare the two operands with the `<` (less than), `>` (greater than) operators.

```
if(countertimeslots < t && countertimeslots > 22){
```